# how is data transfer between meteor and mongo secure?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, node-mongodb-native

How does the server and client connect to the mongo db such that the communication between client--mongo and server--mongo is secure? Is this something meteor already takes care of or is it already default?

Comment: just one thing to understand your question are you asking about the connection itself or about the update in the database and who can change the data in the server

Comment: the connection itself. i am NOT referring to using any kind of role based access to determine collection access. how is the communication secured such that replay attacks/eavesdropping and other attacks are prevented? does using https solve all our problems client side? if so, how do we secure server to db communication?

Comment: Every production Meteor app that handles user data should run with SSL.

please read https://guide.meteor.com/security.html

Comment: So ssl between server and client. Then also ssl between db and server...?

Comment: between server and client yes, between db and server i don't know what you mean but for the projects that i made the db was on the server

Comment: If you are using https then the data is encrypted. Meteor uses sockets (or secure sockets) to communicate between client and server (ie database) over the connection that you have, either http or https.

Comment: I see. So it sounds like https will make all client interaction secure because minimongo makes a server call anyway to update actual data in the db?  But what about server to db? I have the app and mongo on different servers. When the app server connects to Mom to through the credentials set in environment variables and it does a collection.find(), how do we secure the data the in transit between the app and mongo?

Comment: i see mongo supports ssl and the the mongodb node driver (which i think meteor uses...? also supports ssl. how can i enable ssl between server and mongo in meteor?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/tutorials/connect/ssl/

Answer (score 0):

mongo enterprise supports ssl connections.

meteor does use mongo node driver which also supports ssl connections.

so if you want server <---> db connection to be secure, we need to enable ssl on the mongo instance and the driver.

to do so with a self signed certificate as instructed in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/:

> For testing purposes, you can generate a self-signed certificate and private key on a Unix system with a command that resembles the following:
>
> openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out mongodb-cert.crt -keyout mongodb-cert.key
>
> Once you have the certificate, concatenate the certificate and private key to a .pem file, as in the following example:
>
> cat mongodb-cert.key mongodb-cert.crt > mongodb.pem

and run mongod with...

> mongod --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile

When setting up the Meteor environment variables for mongo db connections...

set...

MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/?ssl=true